# Web service response is MessageElement?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to figure out how to use this service, which should print out holidays in US: http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL

So, I generated Java classes for it, and tried to call its method, which should return list of available countries:

```
holidayServiceLocator.getHolidayServiceSoap().getCountriesAvailable().get_any()
```

`getAny()` method returns `org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement[]` type of object, and this is where I am lost.

As I can understand, MessageElement is used in order to store XML, am I correct? In that case, how should I handle it in order to get correct result (list of supported countries for this service)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `MessageElement.getElementsByTagName(String name)` if you know the tag names in the response or you can use `MessageElement.getChildElements()` to iterate through all of them one by one.